# Convert existing CDK App into CDK Pipeline

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

Is it possible to wrap an existing CDK App into a pipeline, to have the option of creating a pipeline for the application but also doing the regular `cdk deploy -all` if just wanting to deploy the app locally?

Our current main app looks something like this (over simplified, but just to give idea):

```js
const app = describeApp()
const coreStack = new CoreStack(app, 'CoreStack')
const domainConfig = new DomainConfig(app, 'DomainConfig')
...
```

What I would then like to do, is add something at the bottom along the lines of:

```js
if (process.env.CREATE_PIPELINE) {
    const pipelineApp = new App();
    new PipelineStack(pipelineApp, 'PipelineStack', app);
}
```

With a PipelineStack class that effectively adds the main app as a stage to a pipeline, eg:

```js
export class PipelineStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, app: App, props?: StackProps) {

        super(scope, id, props);

        const repo = codeCommit.Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, 'Repo', 'XXX')

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            pipelineName: 'Pipeline',
            synth: new CodeBuildStep('SynthStep', {
                    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, 'YYY'),
                    installCommands: [
                        'npm install -g yarn',
                        'cd app',
                        'yarn install',
                        'yarn global add aws-cdk'
                    ],
                    commands: [
                        'yarn build',
                        'cdk synth'
                    ]
                }
            )
        });

        pipeline.addStage(app) 
    }
}
```

This currently complains about my stage not having a stageName, but if I add the hack:

```js
        // @ts-ignore
        app.stageName = 'DeployApp'
```

I then get errors around `Error: Pipeline stack which uses cross-environment actions must have an explicitly set region`.

I feel like there must be a more straightforward way of doing this, but without re-writing my main app class to ONLY allow me to deploy via this new pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  The important point here is that "local" and "pipeline" deploys have different construct hierarchies:

- local: `App > (CoreStack, DomainConfig)`
- pipeline: `App > PipelineStack > Stage > (CoreStack, DomainConfig)`

Because the stacks' parent is different in each case, it's useful to wrap your app's stacks in a reusable construct. The [MyService example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/stacks.html) also uses this pattern.

```js
// AppStacks.ts
export class AppStacks extends Construct {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App | cdk.Stage, id: string, props: AppStacksProps) {
    super(scope, id);
    const coreStack = new CoreStack(this, 'CoreStack', props)
    const domainConfig = new DomainConfig(this, 'DomainConfig', props)
  }
}
```

For *local* (`cdk deploy`) deploys, your stacks, wrapped in `AppStacks`, are children of the App:

```js
// app.ts
const app = new App();
new AppStacks(app, 'Stacks', props);
```

For *pipeline* deploys, your stacks are children of a Stage, and the Stage is added to the Pipeline.

```js
// DeployStage.ts
export class DeployStage extends cdk.Stage {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: DeployStageProps) {
    super(scope, id, { ...props, env: props.config.env });

    new AppStacks(this, 'Stacks', props);
  }
}
```

```js
// app-pipeline.ts
const app = new App();
new PipelineStack(app, 'Pipeline', props); // add the stage: pipeline.addStage(new DeployStage...)
```

I prefer to put my pipeline app setup in a separate file.  But you could also have one "app" file with conditional logic, as in the OP.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. I think my issue was coming from the fact I didn't wan't to have two versions of the app definition, as we have 20+ stacks being defined. We also have created our own extension of the App class with lots of business logic in it, which adds further complications for having a 'dynamic' hierarchy.


I think I may have gotten it to work using the above code, I just needed to pass in the same env properties when creating the pipeline stack so it has matching account/region. Will report back if its successful!

Comment: @Charlie  Hmm.  The pipeline hierarchy would then be `App > Pipeline > Stage > App > (20 Stacks)`.  It's a question of whether a two-root hierarchy messes up the pipeline's [construct tree](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/constructs.html#constructs_tree).

Comment: @Charlie BTW, my suggestion of adding an intermediate `AppStacks` construct can done with \*zero effects\* on the synthed CloudFormation template.  Either set your stack names explicitly or change `this` to `scope` in the `AppStacks` constructor.  Run a snapshot test and convince yourself!

Comment: @fedorev thanks for the tips! I think I've managed to get it working (working through some different build issues at the moment) but will see if I can clean it up a little with your suggestions next week

Comment: @fedorev I'm now having a different issue, where by the Assets stage is failing to find a buildSpec file. Let me know if you have any ideas!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74431793/aws-cdk-pipeline-assets-stage-fails-to-find-buildspec-fileasset-yaml-when-publi