# AWS CDK Pipeline: Assets stage fails to find buildSpec FileAsset.yaml when publishAssetsInParallel is disabled

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

We are trying to get our multi-stack application deployed using the cdk pipeline library.

We have recently disabled the publishAssetsInParallel flag, as with the default setting our pipeline would create >20 FileAsset objects under the Assets stage, which AWS then complains as being too many CodeBuild projects running parallel.

However, with this property now disabled, I'm getting the following error for the Assets stage:

```
[Container] 2022/11/14 12:04:24 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2022/11/14 12:04:24 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: stat /codebuild/output/src112668013/src/buildspec-c866864112c35d54804951dbe96b99440c9b891fde-FileAsset.yaml: no such file or directory
```

I'm assuming this is supposed to be a build spec that is create by cdk pipeline, as we didn't need to create a build spec when things were running in parallel.

Here is the current pipeline code:

```
      const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            publishAssetsInParallel: false,
            selfMutation: false,
            pipelineName: fullStackName('Pipeline', app),
            synth: new CodeBuildStep('SynthStep', {
                    input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, repoBranchName, {codeBuildCloneOutput: true}),
                    buildEnvironment: {computeType: ComputeType.MEDIUM},
                    installCommands: [
                        'npm install -g yarn',
                        'yarn install',
                        'cd apps/cloud-app',
                        'yarn install',
                        'yarn global add aws-cdk'
                    ],
                    commands: [
                        'yarn build',
                        'cdk synth'
                    ],
                    primaryOutputDirectory: 'apps/cloud-app/cdk.out'
                }
            )
        });
```

UPDATE:
I reverted the publishAssetsInParallel flag to its default setting to compare, and it seems there is a fundamental difference in the way it creates the FileAsset CodeBuild projects based on this flag. With it enabled, when I inspect the build details for one of the FileAsset projects that is created, I can see under the buildspec section it contains a concrete implementation of a build spec, eg:

```
{
  "version": "0.2",
  "phases": {
    "install": {
      "commands": [
        "npm install -g cdk-assets@2"
      ]
    },
    "build": {
      "commands": [
        "cdk-assets --path \"MyStack.assets.json\" --verbose publish \"2357296280127ce793d8dbb13e6c907db22f5dcc57a173ba77fcd19a76d8f444:12345678910-eu-west-2\""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

With the flag disabled, the buildspec simply contains a pointer to a buildspec file as below, which it then fails to find...

```
buildspec-c866864112c35d54804951dbe96b99440c9b891fde-FileAsset.yaml
```

Comment: Apologies, have marked your answer as accepted as you no doubt are more knowledgeable on this subject than I. As I said we've since moved to the much simpler (and quicker!) approach of performing the whole build and deploy on one box, made quicker still using the "concurrency" flag with cdk deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-mutation has to be enabled - currently, asset updates mutate the pipeline.

Reference: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9080

Comment: I'm not sure this is the cause, as I can see with publishAssetsInParallel: true and selfMutation:false, the build specs have already been correctly populated in the Assets stage before the UpdatePipeline stage is ran. Either way, I had to disable selfMutation due to a different "No stacks match the name(s) MyPipelineStack" issue which I've been unable to resolve. I've decided CDK Pipeline is way more complicated than its worth, even if I could get it to work it appears it would have been slower than the current implementation which is just to build and deploy within a single CodeBuild project.

Comment: The build spec is only "populated" (i.e. modified) in the self-mutation step. It stays constant otherwise, which does not work here.